# Circumcenter coordinates for a isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

I'm back, wow, twice a day nowadays. I need to calculate **circumcenter coordinates** (or at least I hope they're called that) at point **C** for an  **isosceles** triangle (the circle must be such, that created triangle is). I know the point **O** (origin), two vectors **p** and **q** (length may differ) originating in that point (leading to points **P** and **Q**). I also know the radius **r** of this to be circumscribed circle. When the circle's center is known it should create said green highlighted isosceles triangle. Here is drawing for better understanding:

[image]

Comment: Is the triangle you care about $Opq$ or $OPQ$? If $Opq$ how are the points $p$ and $q$ determined? (increasing the size of the circle changes the location of the points)

Comment: Hi, p and q are vectors p is O->P, q is O->Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{p}^0,\mathbf{q}^0$ denote the vectors $\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q}$ normalized to unit length. As the triangle is to be isosceles, $\mathbf{C}$ lies on the ray bisecting the rays $\mathbf{OP}$ and $\mathbf{OQ}$. The direction of that ray can be computed as
$$\mathbf{v} = (\mathbf{p}^0+\mathbf{q}^0)^0$$
With $r$ given, you know that $\mathbf{C}$ is located precisely $r\mathbf{v}$ from $\mathbf{O}$.

Comment: That is indeed a correct solution, thanks.